# Is there any situation that require a posttest loop instead of iterating at least once?

Tags: loops

I am wondering in what other situations will you need to use a post test loop like do while loop , any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Your title doesn't make all that much sense - a post-test loop **does** iterate at least once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a loop with the test at the end when at least one iteration of the loop is required.

For example, when you prompt user for data, validate the input, and continue until the user enters a valid value, you should use a `do` / `while` loop:

```
 int value;
 do {
     System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 10, inclusive");
     value = scanner.nextInt();
     // This is only an example - more processing may be needed here.
 } while (value < 0 || value > 10);
```

Obviously, in this situation you need to prompt the user at least once. If the user enters a good value right away, the loop does not go back to prompting him; otherwise, the loop goes on until a valid value is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Example of typical usage of do .. while() loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInt;

    do
    {
        cout << "Insert an integer >= 0: ";
        cin >> positiveInt;
    } while (positiveInt < 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think he was looking for an example of a `do while` loop... more like an explanation of when a post-test is preferred to a pre-test.